# Python: read folders that are not ZIP folders

Tags: python

Currently I read folders individually like so:

```
input_location = r'path\202206'
```

I would like to read in all the folders at once + not read in the zipped files.

[image]

Essentially the logic id like to perform is `input_location = r'path\202206' + r'path\202207' + r'path\202207' + r'path\202208'`

I cant just do `input_location = r'path\` as it may read in those zip files I do not want.

Is there a way to read in the folders without reading in the zip files? Or explicitly list the folder names in one variable (input_location)?

Comment: Is this question sufficient "Is there a way to read in the folders without reading in the zip files?" or is more detail needed?

Comment: Could you show the code you use to read the entries in the folder?

Comment: @Matthias , I currently just read in 1 folder at a time  ,  `input_location = r'path\202206' `. I dont read them in at once. I have to run my script 4 times to get desired result  right now.

Comment: @Jonnyboi could you not just turn that into a loop? If you google "python read all files in directory" you get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3207219/12479639) as your top result with quite a few answers. From there it seems like your only question would be "How do I determine if a string ends with ".zip"?". Hint: `str.endwith('.zip')`

Comment: @Axe319 `os.listdir` and `glob` was OK at the time the answer was written. Nowadays you would use `pathlib`.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC: Collecting all directories from a directory can be done using a simple list comprehension as follows.

The `glob` library is nice, as it returns the *full* filepath, whereas a function such as `os.listdir()` only returns the filenames.

```
import os
from glob import glob

dirs = [f for f in glob('/path/to/files/*') if os.path.isdir(f)]
```

Output:

```
['/path/to/files/202207', 
 '/path/to/files/202206', 
 '/path/to/files/202208',  
 '/path/to/files/202209']
```

Then, your script can iterate over the list of directories as required.

---

For completeness, the directory content is a follows:

```
202206
202206.zip
202207
202207.zip
202208
202208.zip
202209
202209.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) from Pythons standard library you can get all entries in the folder and check if the entry is a folder.

```
from pathlib import Path

for entry in Path('/path/to/folder').glob('*'):
    if entry.is_dir():
        print(entry)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `os` base approach. Notice that `os.listdir` returns the content of the directory in a basename form and not as a path.

```
import os

def my_dirs(wd):
    return list(filter(os.path.isdir, (os.path.join(wd, f) for f in os.listdir('.'))))

working_dir = # add path

print(*my_dirs(working_dir), sep='\n')
```

Remarks: to make your program platform independent you always stuffs like `os.path.join` or `os.sep` for path manipulation